# Parser Error(could not read state "obj\Debug\ResolveAssemblyReference.cache) while loading an asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i got an error while loading a page in asp.net.I have renamed the page before loading it.The error is as follows:-

****could not read state "obj\Debug\ResolveAssemblyReference.cache"****

Please help

Comment: Does the project build ok and does file name of the codebehind file match that of the value enterd in the asp.net page directive?

Comment: filename is same in codebehind and in asp.net page directive

Comment: build failed.got the above error

Comment: @Vineetha: Tag is used to identify tools. "with" cannot be a right tag of your question. Also, I have changed it to have vb.net instead of vb. You can modify it, if that is not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need to clear your ASP.NET cache directory, located in:

> C: \ Windows directory \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework \ v2.0.50727 \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \

Navigate to that directory and delete all folders in it.

Or Perhaps resetting your IIS will do the trick:

1. Hit Windows-key + R
2. Type "cmd" to open up the console
3. Hit enter
4. Type "iisreset" to reboot your IIS
5. Hit enter

Or perhaps Visual Studio crapped out on you when you re-named the file. Check so see if your *.aspx* page is referencing it's *.aspx.cs* code-behind file and partial class correctly:

```
// First line of Default.aspx:
<%@ Page CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

The *Inherits* property should be set to your partial class's name in your *.aspx.cs* code-behind file. The *CodeFile* property should point to your *.aspx.cs.* code-behind file.